# <strong> not working inside <p> in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that when using `<strong>` inside a `<p>` the text isn't getting bold. This only happens in Firefox – in Chrome and Safari all works.
When I'm using `<strong>` inside a `<li>` all is working correct.

Does anyone else have the same problem?

Is it a proper way to fix this by applying `font-weight: bold;` to `<strong>`?

```html
<ul>
  <li>Normal</li>
  <li><strong>Strong</strong></li>
  <li>
    <p><strong>Strong</strong></p>
  </li>
</ul>

<p><strong>Strong</strong></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: All strongs are strong in my Firefox 94 in the snippet I made you

Comment: if you want your text to be bold, you can also use `<b>` it is inline and shorter than `strong`

Comment: You need to verify what styling is Firefox applying, the observations above are correct: strong looks as expected on Firefox 94.0, and it should work. So, there's something on your local installation of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that the `strong` works properly in the current firefox version for both usages in your snippet i would not recommend to rely on the browsers default styles as they could change whenevery without you noticing.

Set your `font-weight` explicitly instead to ensure a consistent display of your text across browsers.

So to answer your question:

> Is it a proper way to fix this by applying font-weight: bold; to ?

Yes, 100%!

I extended your snippet with the neccessary css.

```css
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Normal</li>
  <li><strong>Strong</strong></li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong>Strong</strong>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>

<p>
  <strong>Strong</strong>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **strong** tag works properly on the current version of Firefox.

- Is it a proper way to fix this by applying font-weight: bold;?

Yes. Using CSS, you can get consistent results across browsers.